# Java String to Method Map library

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dictionary, mapping

Is there any Map like

MAP < String, FunctionMethod >

library in Java? No, there isn't. Then any external or open source library available?

Comment: Java has some classes for maps, but that's not what you're looking for !?

Comment: Your question is very confusing to me. What do you mean *specifically* by MAP library?

Comment: http://geotools.org/ you can always use google maps with java .

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I'm sorry. I wrote < String, FunctionMethod > without the space and the text processor took it as a tag :D

Comment: Are you referring to a function pointer as the value in your map?

Comment: @Gary Yes! I have a string and I want to invoke a corresponding method... Like a mapping of MAP < String, MethodName > I know there isn't anything like it. But I'm searching for external library

Comment: @Dewsworld In that case, Andreas_D has the most straightforward solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does not support function pointers. A workaround is using reflection and a Map

```
Map<String, java.lang.reflect.Method>
```

and invoke mapped method.

Answer (score 3):

Another work around is to map a String to an Interface a la the command pattern

```
Map<String, MyInterface>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am curious if you are looking for something like guava's [MapMaker](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r303/trunk/gwt-javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html)'s `makeComputingMap`. It takes a (com.google.common.base.)Function that computes the value. I use it in web apps to implement lazy, cached key-value pairs. What do you mean by "FunctionMethod"?

Comment: Function/Method, actually. I just need to invoke a method with a given string KEY